# Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems Simple Wikipedia

Tags: logic, solution-verification, incompleteness

I recently wrote the outline of the proof of [Gödel’s incompleteness theorems](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) for Simple Wikipedia. I would like to get feedback on its clarity and logical validity so that I can make further improvements. I’ve reproduced relevant sections from the Simple Wikipedia article below.

**Gödel’s Theorems**

Gödel said that every non-trivial formal system (consistent and axiomatic system with theorems listable by following an algorithm) is incomplete and not provably consistent:

1. There will always be questions that cannot be answered, using a certain set of axioms; there are truths that cannot be proved using the axioms of the system.
2. You cannot prove that a system of axioms is consistent according to the axioms of the system.

**Outline of Proof of Gödel’s Theorems**

The proof of Gödel’s theorems is based on forming and considering [special self-referential statements](https://web.archive.org/web/20230907041330/https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-godels-proof-works-20200714/).

One way to prove the theorems is to consider the first theorem before considering the second theorem. There are three parts in this proof:

- A. Consider the first theorem and the truth of this first statement “This statement cannot be proved”: proving this first statement would be a contradiction because there would then be a proof for a statement that cannot be proved. For the sake of the consistency of the system, the first statement and hence the first theorem are therefore true but unprovable.
- B. Recall from part A that if we were able to prove the first statement then our system would be inconsistent. Thus to prove the consistency of the system, we must prove that the first statement is not provable (ie: prove the contrapositive of the claim “if we were able to prove the first statement then our system would be inconsistent”). Because of self-reference in the first statement “this statement cannot be proved” (ie: proving the first statement is not provable is proving the first statement), therefore proof of the consistency of the system requires proof of the first statement.
- C. Recall in part A that consistency of the system is why the first statement is true and unprovable. Hence by the truth of the first statement and the conclusion in part B, it follows that the consistency of the system cannot be proved with the axioms of the system. Hence the second theorem is established. The truth of the first theorem is established in part A.

Thanks for taking the time to proof-read and contemplate the statements!

Comment: [Already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774224/g%c3%b6del-incompleteness-theorems-proof) some days ago.

Comment: This sort of writing probably is why Godel hesitated to publish.  "every non-trivial formal system"  No, I don't think he said that.  He didn't call any formal system "trivial".  There are some features of formal systems that have eluded scholars for decades and only got understood recently even.  It also comes as worth the time to note that Peano Arithmetic, got proved consistent by Gentzen in 1936 after Godel's work.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: Thank you for telling me this! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975294/why-wouldnt-someone-accept-gentzens-consistency-proof says you can only prove a system is consistent using a larger system whose consistency is itself unprovable without a yet larger system whose consistency must also be proved. Another user wrote the words non-trivial and I am curious if this is what was meant in this context.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza: I saw the previous post was closed and was invited to add details and create a new post, so I created this new post with details from the page including the proof outline section I contributed. I appreciate the suggestion! This page has more views and I look forward to being able to improve the article further

Comment: Why referring to Quanta's web page, that ends with a comment dated 1958? Why not using SEP's entry on GIT for details: it is much more up to date.

Comment: Re A: "Consider the first theorem and the truth of this first statement “This statement cannot be proved”" Unfortunately, this sort of summary gives a sort of "magic feel" to the proof where there is none. The machinery of the proof produce a formula $G$ in the language of the system such that neither $G$ nor $\lnot G$ are provable in the system. At this level of summary it is enough, avoiding the self-referential aspect that can be misleading.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza: I like the Quanta Magazine article because I found it insightful and accessible. Quanta says it was published in July 2020. I added a slightly different version of its proof of the second theorem to Simple Wikipedia. Thank you for pointing out Stanford’s Encyclopedia of Philosophy!

Comment: @MauroAllegranza: G and ~G cannot both be true in a consistent system. But ~G is the statement “this statement can be proved” and I see no contradiction if only ~G were proved. I think self-reference is an essential component to come to conclude Gödel’s incompleteness theorems.

Comment: "I think self-reference is an essential component to come to conclude Gödel’s incompleteness theorems. " That is simply false. For example, you can elegantly prove the first incompleteness from Kleene's Normal Form Theorem. See for example §§43.6--43.8 of the second edition of my book Intro to Gödel's Theorem (now downloadable from logic matters.net). Where's the self-reference in that sort of argument?

Comment: @Caleb As to "non-trivial", *some* qualifier is needed as it is not true that any consistent axiomatic system with axioms listable by an algorithm is incomplete. Usually in a non-technical explanation, it's stipulated that the system "represents enough arithmetic", or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your deep comment! I thought about it for a bit and this is my current understanding (feel free to correct my reasoning if you think it is incomplete):
1. I think you can implement Godel's arguments (see proof outline on Simple Wikipedia page) in arithmetic if you choose.
2. I think arithmetic is not necessary to understand Godel's arguments (see proof outline on Simple Wikipedia page).

Therefore I think it is true that Godel's arguments applies to all systems capable of arithmetic but that natural language systems that respect logic and are consistent are also susceptible!